# If there are cases of tense or plural as separate words like particles

Tags: syntax, particles

I am looking for stranger particle-like things, like the [Japanese `wa` particle](http://nihonshock.com/2010/02/particles-the-difference-between-wa-and-ga/), or determiners like `the`. So wondering if there are any cases of pluralizing or changing to past/future tense that is *not* an affix of some kind, and also is not just an expression made out of words like "... in the past". So basically instead of having "The paper**s** are new" or "I walk**ed** to the store", it would be more like "The paper **PLURAL** are new" or "I walk **PAST** to the store". Those caps tokens would be basically *modifiers* of some kind, that are separate from the other words (they are standalone instead of affixes). This could also work for gender perhaps, so instead of "**He** walked by" it would be "They **MAN** walked by". Wondering if this sort of thing appears in any language not just English.

Comment: That doesn't count because it's still attached to the word.

Comment: Whether there's a space or not is just orthographic convention. Languages like Vietnamese separate every syllable with a space, even for two syllable words!

Comment: @curiousdannii I know possessive `'s` is a clitic, but why do you say plural `s` is?

Comment: Malay tenses, what there is of them, are all separate auxiliaries; this is true in many other Indonesian languages.

Comment: English (again): "I walk to the store"/"I will walk to the store"/"I did walk to the store".

Comment: There are plenty of examples of such things, particularly of course among the more highly isolating languages such as [Kéo (Austronesian)](https://openresearch-repository.anu.edu.au/handle/1885/9446)

Comment: @Draconis Oops, I meant possessive. Brain fart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

English future tense is a separate word, as in "he **will** be here". English only distinguishes past/non-past with morphology; all other TAM distinctions use auxiliaries.

Latin also lacks certain tenses in its morphology, and uses *periphrasis* (sequences of multiple words) to fill in the gaps. In these cases, the tense distinctions are marked with auxiliaries: *locūtus sum* "I spoke", *locūtus eram* "I had spoken", *locūtus erō* "I will be speaking".

In general, using auxiliaries to express tense distinctions isn't rare—you see it in many European languages, but also in e.g. Bantu.

For plurals, look at Mandarin. What exactly counts as a "word" in Mandarin (and, honestly, in general) is up for debate, but their plural marker 们 *men* is often considered separate. For example 我 *wǒ* "me" → 我们 *wǒ men* "us", 朋友 *péng you* "friend" → 朋友们 *péng you mén* "friends". Mandarin in general doesn't use pluralization much—*men* is only usable with a certain class of words, and can always be left off if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Cebuano

- *tawo* *n* man
- *pl* *mga tawo* (mga + tawo ) or *katawhan* (ka- + tawo + -han)

Comment: Can you add glosses, so that we can easily read off what the Cebuano words mean?